# Can't get the variable correctly in Radiobutton in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a quiz game and for now, I have 4 questions and I put them on the screen in 2 loops.
Now I want to get the variable that is in the radio button but every time I'd try to do it I get the variable from the first question again and again.

So I basically want to get the variable that the user clicked on and compare it with the real answer and tell if he is wrong and I can't do it because it gives me the value of the first question not matter what.

```
from tkinter import *


def sumbit():
    name = entry_name.get()
    print(name)

def instructions_Window():
    instructions_Window = Toplevel()
    instructions_Window.title("instructions")

    instructions = Label(
            instructions_Window,
            text = "WELCOME TO THE TRIVIA GAME!\nYour will answer 10 question, the questions will be about general knowledge.\nMake sure you are doing your best maybe you will on the leaderboard soon!\n GOOD LUCK!!!",
            font = ("Staatliches",30))
    instructions.pack()

    back_but = Button(instructions_Window, text="Back", command=instructions_Window.destroy)
    back_but.pack()

def trivia_Window():
    def clear():
        WaitState.set(1)
        for widgets in trivia_Window.winfo_children():
            widgets.destroy()

    trivia_Window = Toplevel()
    trivia_Window.title("Q&A")
    trivia_Window.config(bg="#858585")

    x = StringVar()
    WaitState = StringVar()
    i = 0

    for key in questions:
        j = 0

        question_number = 1
        question_label = Label(trivia_Window, text=key, bg="#858585",font=("Squada One",40,"bold"))
        question_label.pack()

        continue_but = Button(trivia_Window, text="Continue", font=("Knewave",25,"bold"), bg="#942222" , command=clear)
        continue_but.pack()

        for index in options[question_number-1]:
            options_radio = Radiobutton(trivia_Window, text=options[i][j], variable=x, value=index,bg="#858585", font=("Squada One",40,"bold"))
            options_radio.pack(anchor=W)
            question_number = question_number + 1
            j += 1
            print(x.get())

        i += 1
        continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)

questions = {
     "How old is the universe?": "B",
     "Who was the first person in space?": "C",
     "In which year the first covid-19 case was discovered?": "C",
     "What is the most populated country?": "A"
}

options = [[["A. 5.3 billion years old"], ["B. 13.8 billion years old"], ["C. 13.8 milion years old"], ["D. 241.1 billion years old"]],
          [["A. Alan Shepard"], ["B. Neil Armstrong"], ["C. Yuri Alekseyevich Gagarin"], ["D. Ilan Ramon"]],
          [["A. 2018"], ["B. 2001"], ["C. 2019"], ["D.2020"]],
          [["A. China"],["B. Russia"], ["C. India"], ["D. United States"]]]

window = Tk()
window.title("Home")
window.geometry("1920x1080")
window.iconbitmap("pp.ico")
window.config(bg="#93b4ba")

label_welcome = Label(window, text="Welcome Back To Our Trivia Game!", font=("Akaya Kanadaka",80,"bold"), bg = "#93b4ba")
label_welcome.pack()

label_enter_name = Label(window, text="Enter you name:", font=("Lato",50,"bold"), bg = "#93b4ba", fg="#3038d1")
label_enter_name.pack(side=LEFT)

entry_name = Entry(window,font=("Arial",40))
entry_name.pack(side=LEFT)

sumbit_but = Button(window, text="Sumbit", font=("Arial",10,"bold"), width=15, height=4,command=sumbit, bg="#0f0f0f", fg="white")
sumbit_but.pack(side=LEFT)

quit_but = Button(window, text="Quit", font=("Arial",10,"bold"), width=20, height=10,command=quit,bg="#b5aa72")
quit_but.place(x=0,y=845)

start_but = Button(window, text="Start", font=("Arial",10,"bold"), width=20, height=10,command=trivia_Window ,bg="#a1ad90")
start_but.place(x=1750,y=845)

instructions_but = Button(window, text="Instructions", font=("Arial",10,"bold"), width=20, height=10,command=instructions_Window,bg="#626363")
instructions_but.pack(side=RIGHT)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The only place you are retrieving the value of the `StringVar` is in a loop in the `trivia_Window()` callback function immediately after each `Radiobutton` is created, so of course the value is always the same. Please provide a [mre] and perhaps someone will be able to help you fix things.

Comment: Basically you can do what you said inside `clear()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it could be done. I changed the layout of your GUI because the screen on my system isn't the same size as yours, and I needed to be able to run it while developing an answer for you. I also made *numerous* other modifications to simplify things and make it more readable, as well as to fix several bugs I encountered along the way — but it's still has  the same basic architecture as yours and uses `Radiobutton`s.

I renamed your `clear()` function to `_continue()` since that's the name of the `Button` that calls is. It's were you can check the user's latest answer vs the correct one — there's a comment in it showing where it would go but the code currently doesn't have anything because I don't know how you want to handle correct vs incorrect answers — so like they say, that's an exercise left to the reader. `;¬)`

```
from tkinter import *


def submit():
    name = entry_name.get()
    print(name)

def instructions_Window():
    instructions_Window = Toplevel()
    instructions_Window.title("Instructions")

    instructions = Label(instructions_Window,
                         text=("WELCOME TO THE TRIVIA GAME!\n"
                               "You will answer 10 questions, and the questions will be "
                                   "about general knowledge.\n"
                               "Make sure you are doing your best maybe you will on the "
                                   "leaderboard soon!\n "
                               "GOOD LUCK!!!"),
                         font=("Staatliches",30))
    instructions.pack()

    ok_btn = Button(instructions_Window, text="OK", command=instructions_Window.destroy)
    ok_btn.pack()

def trivia_Window():
    CLEAR = '_NONE_'  # Value indicating no radiobutton has been selected.
    ABORT = 99  # Value WaitState is set to indicate user closed trivia_Window.

    def _continue():
        print(f'{user_ans.get()=}, {correct_ans=}')
        #### ---> Can compare user's answer to correct answer here.
        user_ans.set(CLEAR)  # Clear control variable for next question.
        WaitState.set(1)  # Allow next question to be displayed
        for widgets in trivia_Window.winfo_children():
            widgets.destroy()

    def on_close():
        trivia_Window.destroy()
        WaitState.set(ABORT)

    trivia_Window = Toplevel()
    trivia_Window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
    trivia_Window.title("Q&A")
    trivia_Window.config(bg="#858585")

    WaitState = IntVar()
    user_ans = StringVar(value=CLEAR)
    for question, answers in zip(QUESTIONS, ANSWERS):
        question_label = Label(trivia_Window, text=question, bg="#858585",
                               font=("Squada One",40,"bold"))
        question_label.pack()
        correct_ans = QUESTIONS[question]

        continue_btn = Button(trivia_Window, text="Continue", font=("Knewave",25,"bold"),
                              bg="#942222", command=_continue)
        continue_btn.pack()

        for answer in answers:
            options_radio = Radiobutton(trivia_Window, text=answer, variable=user_ans,
                                        value=answer, bg="#858585",
                                        font=("Squada One",40,"bold"))
            options_radio.pack(anchor=W)

        continue_btn.wait_variable(WaitState)  # Wait for Continue button click.
        if WaitState.get() == ABORT:  # User closed window?
            return

    trivia_Window.destroy()

QUESTIONS = {
     "How old is the universe?": "B",
     "Who was the first person in space?": "C",
     "In which year the first covid-19 case was discovered?": "C",
     "What is the most populated country?": "A"
}

ANSWERS = [["A. 5.3 billion years old", "B. 13.8 billion years old",
            "C. 13.8 million years old", "D. 241.1 billion years old"],
           ["A. Alan Shepard", "B. Neil Armstrong", "C. Yuri Alekseyevich Gagarin",
            "D. Ilan Ramon"],
           ["A. 2018", "B. 2001", "C. 2019", "D. 2020"],
           ["A. China", "B. Russia", "C. India", "D. United States"]]


window = Tk()
window.title("Home")
#window.geometry("1920x1080")
window.geometry("1600x1200")
#window.iconbitmap("pp.ico")
window.config(bg="#93b4ba")

label_welcome = Label(window, text="Welcome Back To Our Trivia Game!",
                      font=("Akaya Kanadaka", 60, "bold"), bg="#93b4ba")
label_welcome.pack()

name_frame = Frame(window, bg="#93b4ba")
name_frame.pack(fill=X)

btn_frame = Frame(window, bg="#93b4ba")
btn_frame.pack(fill=X)

label_enter_name = Label(name_frame, text="Enter you name:", font=("Lato",50,"bold"),
                         bg="#93b4ba", fg="#3038d1")
label_enter_name.pack(side=LEFT)

entry_name = Entry(name_frame,font=("Arial",40))
entry_name.pack(side=LEFT)

submit_btn = Button(name_frame, text="Submit", font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
                    width=15, height=4, command=submit, bg="#0f0f0f", fg="white")
submit_btn.pack(side=LEFT)

instructions_btn = Button(btn_frame, text="Instructions", font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
                          width=20, height=10, command=instructions_Window, bg="#626363")
instructions_btn.pack(side=LEFT)

start_btn = Button(btn_frame, text="Start", font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
                   width=20, height=10, command=trivia_Window, bg="#a1ad90")
start_btn.pack(side=LEFT)

quit_btn = Button(btn_frame, text="Quit", font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
                  width=20, height=10, command=window.quit, bg="#b5aa72")
quit_btn.pack(side=LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't work out a solution with radio buttons (although there probably is a possible solution). However, I've managed to succeed with normal buttons.

Basically, I've just rewritten your radio buttons to normal buttons, then defined commands (A,B,C,D) that change the answer value. After that I just threw an if statement to compare the answer to the value of the key in the for loop.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

answer = ""


def sumbit():
    name = entry_name.get()
    print(name)


def instructions_Window():
    instructions_Window = Toplevel()
    instructions_Window.title("instructions")

    instructions = Label(
        instructions_Window,
        text="WELCOME TO THE TRIVIA GAME!\nYour will answer 10 question, the questions will be about general knowledge.\nMake sure you are doing your best maybe you will on the leaderboard soon!\n GOOD LUCK!!!",
        font=("Staatliches", 30))
    instructions.pack()

    back_but = Button(instructions_Window, text="Back", command=instructions_Window.destroy)
    back_but.pack()


def A():
    global answer
    answer = "A"


def B():
    global answer
    answer = "B"


def C():
    global answer
    answer = "C"


def D():
    global answer
    answer = "D"


def trivia_Window():
    def clear():
        WaitState.set(1)
        for widgets in trivia_Window.winfo_children():
            widgets.destroy()

    trivia_Window = Toplevel()
    trivia_Window.title("Q&A")
    trivia_Window.config(bg="#858585")

    x = StringVar()
    WaitState = StringVar()
    i = 0

    for key in questions:
        question_label = Label(trivia_Window, text=key, bg="#858585", font=("Squada One", 40, "bold"))
        question_label.pack()

        continue_but = Button(trivia_Window, text="Continue", font=("Knewave", 25, "bold"), bg="#942222", command=clear)
        continue_but.pack()

        options_button = Button(trivia_Window, text=options[i][0], command=A)
        options_button2 = Button(trivia_Window, text=options[i][1], command=B)
        options_button3 = Button(trivia_Window, text=options[i][2], command=C)
        options_button4 = Button(trivia_Window, text=options[i][3], command=D)
        options_button.pack(anchor=W)
        options_button2.pack(anchor=W)
        options_button3.pack(anchor=W)
        options_button4.pack(anchor=W)
        i += 1
        continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)
        if answer == questions[key]:
            print("correct, ect")  # & other actions you want to take
        else:
            print("incorrect, ect")  # & other actions you want to take


questions = {
    "How old is the universe?": "B",
    "Who was the first person in space?": "C",
    "In which year the first covid-19 case was discovered?": "C",
    "What is the most populated country?": "A" }

options = [[["A. 5.3 billion years old"], ["B. 13.8 billion years old"], ["C. 13.8 milion years old"],
            ["D. 241.1 billion years old"]],
           [["A. Alan Shepard"], ["B. Neil Armstrong"], ["C. Yuri Alekseyevich Gagarin"], ["D. Ilan Ramon"]],
           [["A. 2018"], ["B. 2001"], ["C. 2019"], ["D.2020"]],
           [["A. China"], ["B. Russia"], ["C. India"], ["D. United States"]]]

window = Tk() window.title("Home") window.geometry("1920x1080") window.config(bg="#93b4ba")

label_welcome = Label(window, text="Welcome Back To Our Trivia Game!", font=("Akaya Kanadaka", 80, "bold"),
                      bg="#93b4ba") label_welcome.pack()

label_enter_name = Label(window, text="Enter you name:", font=("Lato", 50, "bold"), bg="#93b4ba", fg="#3038d1") label_enter_name.pack(side=LEFT)

entry_name = Entry(window, font=("Arial", 40)) entry_name.pack(side=LEFT)

sumbit_but = Button(window, text="Sumbit", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), width=15, height=4, command=sumbit, bg="#0f0f0f",
                    fg="white") sumbit_but.pack(side=LEFT)

quit_but = Button(window, text="Quit", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), width=20, height=10, command=quit, bg="#b5aa72") quit_but.place(x=0, y=845)

start_but = Button(window, text="Start", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), width=20, height=10, command=trivia_Window,
                   bg="#a1ad90") start_but.place(x=1750, y=845)

instructions_but = Button(window, text="Instructions", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), width=20, height=10,
                          command=instructions_Window, bg="#626363") instructions_but.pack(side=RIGHT)

window.mainloop()
```

Probably not the best solution, as I'm a beginner and it ain't fancy either but hey, it works.